# Turtles own after change of breed

Tags: netlogo

I have a code in which juveniles (juvis juvi) become adults (adults adult). The current way I have it is that juvis change breed to adults at a set age (determined by a turtles own, j-age). However I have a turtles own for adults (a-age) which I want to be Zero when the juvis change breed to adults. Does this happen automatically, or do I have to add code along the lines of "set a-age 0". I have tried putting that in in various guises and places but always get errors. Current code is as follows:

```
to emergence
  ask juvis
  [if j-age = (juvenile-period * 24) [set breed adults]]
end
```

any advice is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: It should just work. Variables always default to 0. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I wasn't getting an error message but I was not sure if turtles-own automatically set themselves to zero after changing breed. But by what you said they do. Thank you.

Comment: You can test these questions for yourself using PRINT or SHOW statements, such as: SHOW A-AGE

Comment: Good thinking! So I have breeds [juvis juvi] and [adults adult]. In the code mentioned in the original question, did I correctly use the plurals? I want each juvenile to be asked individual and only those to whom the if statement is correct to change breed.    Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When you change breed, any variables owned by the current breed that were not owned by the previous breed are set to 0.

You can test this yourself--just add a SHOW command to show the variable you are curious about!